# mailu server receives emails but cannot send

Tags: email, smtp

As the question states, I can happily receive emails on my mailu server, but when I try to send, nothing is received at the other end. After a while I get an email in my mailu titled: "Delayed Mail (still being retried)" (or similar) and the body like (sensitive parts redacted):

```
This is the mail system at host example.com.

####################################################################
# THIS IS A WARNING ONLY.  YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE. #
####################################################################

Your message could not be delivered for more than 0 hour(s).
It will be retried until it is 5 day(s) old.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                The mail system

<example@hotmail.ca>: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for
    name=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try
    again
```

The last part had changed from `Operation timed out` (`hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.56.33]:25: Operation timed out`) to `Address not available` (`alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c56::1a]:25: Address not available`) to `Host not found, try again` (the above).

I've searched here and Google, but I cannot find any relevant information.

Similar issues were found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496815/can-receive-emails-from-internet-but-cannot-send-emails) (no answers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808967/can-receive-email-but-cant-have-the-server-send-email) (suggestion only).

I know my way around a linux command line/server, I have played with web servers in the past, but I am new to running an email server (this is my first).

If you need any additional info like logs or something, I will happily share.

The DKIM, DMARC, and SPF had been generated as per the mailu documentation and added on the domain.

Comment: The email you see is a [delivery status notification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3461). Your email server is configured to send those. The real problem seems to be DNS: "Host or domain name not found." Make sure your email machine can resolve domain names, in particular mail servers. Run e.g., `host outlook.com` or `dig -t mx outlook.com` to find the mailserver for outlook. Then try to resolve that: `dig outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com`. You should get the IP address for that server. Check your DNS settings if you don't.

Comment: Like I said, there were 3 possible outcomes. The one I listed in the question is from when I tried to force outgoing encryption (I know, not the best timing). I turned it back off and not the most recent message is "... Operation timed out".